# ng-maxlength not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-validation

I have an Angular 4 Application. I am trying to add validation to form inputs, where inputs with numbers should not accept more than 4 digits. If more, it should invalid the form. I am using reactive forms. This is the code.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-amount no-z-index"
     id="forNumber"
     name="forNumber"
     formControlName="forNumber"
     ng-required="true"
     type="number"
     ng-maxlength="4" 
     [(ngModel)]="saveNumber"
    [attr.disabled]="!condition? 'disabled': null "
    #forNumber
  >  

<small class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!form.get('forNumber').valid">
      Invalid input.
 </small>
```

If I enter 11111 it should invalid the entry and should print above alert message; which is not happening.
Any idea what's going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Use `maxlength="{{bind_your_maxlength_variable}}"` instead of `ng-maxlength`

Comment: ng-maxlength for angularjs not for angular

Comment: you are mixing the APIs from angularjs and angular

Comment: I tried this solution, maxlength="{{bind_your_maxlength_variable}}"... And it is still not working

Comment: what to use for Angular 4 then ? if not ng-maxlength. I tried using maxlenght too but it seems it is still allowing more than 4 digits and not making form input invalid

Comment: What is the value your `bind_your_maxlength_variable` holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't use a ngModel and a formControlName together. And I don't know about the ViewChild  reference, and what you do with it, but if it's only to get the value, then you don't need it either.

Second, `ng-` is AngularJS, not Angular.

Third, you need to add a validator to you control.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-amount no-z-index"
  id="forNumber"
  name="forNumber"
  formControlName="forNumber"
  ng-required="true"
  type="number"
  maxlength="4" 
  [attr.disabled]="!condition? 'disabled': null "
>
```

Now, to add the validator, in your TS

```
constructor(private FB: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = FB.group({
    forNumber: ['', [Validators.maxLength(4)]]
  });
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators, you can use, if is a text maxLength, if is number max, in your code <input ... max="9999">

Comment: That is the correct way. Adding that validator in constructor. ThANX A LOT.